# New PC + NVME SSD with over 1TB Total Host Writes in less than a week, should I be concerned?

Tags: memory, ssd, nvme, crystaldiskinfo

I am using a newly build PC (core i5 11th gen, 16gb RAM), with an NVME SSD (WD SN550, 1TB). I ran CrystalDiskInfo and noticed that the Total Host Writes were already over 1TB in less than a week of usage. Is this normal or is something wrong?

Comment: I manage that every week. You've also got the entire installer process as part of that. What's worrying you?

Comment: It just doesn't look right.

Comment: For the first week including the installation process 1TB is IMHO acceptable. Only if the next week gets the same amount without large disk operations/downloads/installations then I would try to identify the source.

Comment: Did you enable bitlocker/full disk encryption? If so, the initial process of encrypting the disk could explain it.

Comment: No, I did not enable encryption.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me seems absolutely normal. Even at this rate (first week is likely to have some extra writes, due to software installation and updates) the 600TBW your drive is rated for should last for arround 600TBW / 1TB/week=600 weeks (12 years)

Since you probably wont use the computer so heavily as this week as I said (at least not installing that much software), and the manufacturers tend to be quite conservative with the TBW value (I still have an intel X-25M G2 from 2008, which was mounted in several PCs, and has 85% of lifespan), I would just ignore it and be happy about your new build.

There are some changes that can be made to minimize host writes, like disabling (or moving to another partition) the pagination file, which should have only a minor impact on performance since you have plenty of RAM for a "normal" use but... What is the point of having a SSD then? Access times are more than an order of magnitude faster than mechanical HDD, and in RAM impaired scenarios is a big performance improvement having the pagefile on flash memory.

Just check the value again in 1 month if that gives you peace of mind. Do not worry, modern OSes and controllers are pretty smart about preserving SSD health.

Comment: I have a secondary HDD (Seagate, 4TB) where I store most of my data, so I have it all set up the way I want.